# Ratingbar in listview

Tags: android, listview

Rating bar is resets when we scroll down in android, I need to send the response of rating feedback to server but it will resets or not saved when i scroll down in listview in android.

```
public class FacultyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Context context;

        public FacultyListAdapter(Context context) {

            this.context = context;

            if (!facultylist.isEmpty())
                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder TabviewHolder;


            if (convertView == null) {

                TabviewHolder = new ViewHolder();


                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_feedback,
                        parent, false);

                TabviewHolder.FacultyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FacultyName);//facultyname

                TabviewHolder.rating = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);//rating starts
                TabviewHolder.Submit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

                // Save the holder with the view
                convertView.setTag(TabviewHolder);
            } else {


                TabviewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            final Faculty mFac = facultylist.get(position);//*****************************NOTICE
            TabviewHolder.FacultyName.setText(mFac.getEmployeename());
            TabviewHolder.rating.setTag(position);
            TabviewHolder.rating.setRating(mFac.getRatingStar());
            //   TabviewHolder.ModuleName.setText(mFac.getSubject());



            TabviewHolder.rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                            boolean fromUser) {

                    feedbackresult =String.valueOf(rating);

                    TabviewHolder.rating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(feedbackresult));
                    Log.d("feedback","feedback is: "+ feedbackresult);

                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        /*private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                    FacultyName item = getItem(position);
                    item.setRatingStar(v);
                    Log.i("Adapter", "star: " + v);
                }
            };
        }*/

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return facultylist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {return facultylist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }
```

Comment: save your rating bar value in your modal class and then get it from your modal

Comment: Try removing condition `if (convertView == null)` , that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Listview and recyclerview auto refresh (recreate) view based on your list passed to it when you scroll.

You have to store your rating to your List<> (i think it is facultylist) in which you contains all details.

When user click on rating you need to store rating to particular index. Then your listview show correct rating based on value in list.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link [Rating Bar in ListView Android](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/rating-bar-in-listview-android.html)

```
public class FeedbackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    static Context context;
    List<FeedbackRowDetails> row;
    ViewHolder holder;
    public FeedbackAdapter(Context context,List<FeedbackRowDetails> row)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.row =row;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_slno, tv_productname, tv_time;
        RatingBar rb_productrating;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) 
        {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_feedback_row_format,parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv_slno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_slno);
            holder.tv_time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            holder.tv_productname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_productname);
            holder.rb_productrating=(RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rb_productrating);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.rb_productrating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(onRatingChangedListener(holder, position));
        holder.rb_productrating.setTag(position);

        holder.tv_slno.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.tv_time.setText(getItem(position).gettime());

        holder.tv_productname.setText(getItem(position).getproductsName());
        float rating=Float.valueOf(getItem(position).getrating());

        holder.rb_productrating.setRating(rating);

        return convertView;

    }

      private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) 
      {
            return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean b) 
                {

                    FeedbackRowDetails item = row.get(position);
                    int roundoff_rating = (int)Math.round(rating);                  
                    ratingBar.setRating(roundoff_rating);
                    item.setrating(String.valueOf(roundoff_rating));

                }
            };
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return row.size();
    }

    @Override
    public FeedbackRowDetails getItem(int position) 
    {
        return row.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return row.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

}
```